# Nodejs spawn ssh tcpdump parameters

Tags: node.js, ssh, tcpdump, remote-host

I need to take random  tcpdump samples from remote host.
Starting tcpdump is not the problem but closing it on remote host is.

**Code below works fine.**

```
var child = spawn('ssh', [ 'a@'+b, 'tcpdump', '-w -', '-i any']);

child.kill()
```

**tcpdump on remote gone.**

**This does not.**

```
var child = spawn('ssh', [ 'a@'+b, 'tcpdump', '-w -', '-i any', 'port 9999']);

child.kill()
```

**tcpdump on remains.**

**This seems to work random.**

```
var child = spawn('ssh', [ 'a@'+b, 'tcpdump', '-w -', '-i any', 'portrange 9999-10010']);

child.kill()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `child.kill('SIGINT');`?

Comment: I have tried sigint, sigterm etc. and it is only port filter with tcpdump  that prevents killing. Without it, pure .kill() works just fine.